# Lotus Notes jvm\lib\ext directory on Mac

Tags: java, macos, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have an application which runs on Lotus Notes 8.5.x. It's basically a modified version of the mail template which has some custom web services connectivity. The web service functionality doesn't use Domino web services design elements.

The web services connectivity requires some custom JAR files to be loaded into the jvm\lib\ext directory on Windows.

This is handled programmatically on load of the mail template. If the relevant files don't exist, they're put in place using the LotusScript ExtractFile() method from the NotesEmbeddedObject class.

This all works fine on Windows.

However I'm unsure about whether the same approach will work on the Notes client on a Mac. I have 3 questions:

1) Does the same principal of JAR files being available in the jvm\lib\ext directory mean those JARs are then effectively on the classpath for agents which are run in the Notes client?

2) The only "jvm/lib/ext" directory I can find on my Mac is actually within the Notes.app file. Is this the Mac equivalent of the jvm\lib\ext directory on Windows?

3) If the answer to 2 is "yes", is it possible to programmatically write to that directory on a Mac?

I suspect the answers to 1 and 2 are "Yes". I have a feeling that writing files to the directory on a Mac from within a LN application is probably not going to work though.

Has anyone ever tried anything similar to this?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Cheers,
Lee

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of `jre\lib\ext` on Mac is `/Library/Java/Extensions`, but better would be if there's some way to set the `java.ext.dirs` system property to point it at a different location that is specific to this application, rather than polluting the "global namespace".